# SLC code not filling all Landsat 7 SR gaps

Tags: json, google-earth-engine, landsat

I am a beginner in Google Earth Engine code and am trying to apply the SLC-gap code to Landsat 7 Surface Reflectance images. Using resources available on StackOverflow, I generated the code below; however, when I bring the images into QGIS, there still appear to be gaps.  Is my code incorrect or did I not properly apply it to the images?

First, I masked the clouds based on the pixel_qa band of Landsat SR data:

```
var cloudMaskL7 = function(image) {
var qa = image.select('pixel_qa');
var cloud = qa.bitwiseAnd(1 << 5)
                  .and(qa.bitwiseAnd(1 << 7))
                  .or(qa.bitwiseAnd(1 << 3));
```

Then, I removed edge pixels that don't occur in all bands:

```
var mask2 = image.mask().reduce(ee.Reducer.min());
return image.updateMask(cloud.not()).updateMask(mask2);
 };
var l7 = ee.ImageCollection('LANDSAT/LE07/C01/T1_SR')
              .filterDate('2004-09-15', '2004-12-31')
              .map(cloudMaskL7);

var visParams = {
bands: ['B3', 'B2', 'B1'],
min: 0,
max: 3000,
gamma: 1.4,
};
Map.setCenter(36.197, 31.701,7);
Map.addLayer(l7.median(), visParams);
```

Then, I mapped the function over one year of Landsat 7 TOA data and took the median and mapped it for Jordan.

```
var composite = l7.map(cloudMaskL7)
    .median();
Map.setCenter(36.124, 31.663);
Map.addLayer(composite, {bands: ['B4', 'B3', 'B2'], max: 0.3});
```

Then, I tried to fill the SLC Landsat 7 gaps by applying the USGS L7 Phase-2 Gap filling protocol, using a single kernel size.

```
var MIN_SCALE = 1/3;
var MAX_SCALE = 3;
var MIN_NEIGHBORS = 144;
var GapFill = function(src, fill, kernelSize) {
var kernel = ee.Kernel.square(kernelSize * 30, 'meters', false);
var common = src.mask().and(fill.mask());
var fc = fill.updateMask(common);
var sc = src.updateMask(common);
```

Then, I found the primary scaling factors with a regression and interleaved the bands for the regression (assumes the bands have the same names).

```
   var regress = fc.addBands(sc);
    regress = regress.select(regress.bandNames().sort());
    var fit = regress.reduceNeighborhood(ee.Reducer.linearFit().forEach(src.bandNames()),  kernel, null, false);
    var offset = fit.select('.*_offset');
    var scale = fit.select('.*_scale');
```

Then, I found the secondary scaling factors using just means and stddev.

```
 var reducer = ee.Reducer.mean().combine(ee.Reducer.stdDev(), null, true);
    var src_stats = src.reduceNeighborhood(reducer, kernel, null, false);
    var fill_stats = fill.reduceNeighborhood(reducer, kernel, null, false);
    var scale2 = src_stats.select('.*stdDev').divide(fill_stats.select('.*stdDev'));
    var offset2 = src_stats.select('.*mean').subtract(fill_stats.select('.*mean').multiply(scale2));

    var invalid = scale.lt(MIN_SCALE).or(scale.gt(MAX_SCALE));
    scale = scale.where(invalid, scale2);
    offset = offset.where(invalid, offset2);
```

I applied the scaling and mask off pixels that didn't have enough neighbors.

```
var count = common.reduceNeighborhood(ee.Reducer.count(), kernel, null, true, 'boxcar');
var scaled = fill.multiply(scale).add(offset)
      .updateMask(count.gte(MIN_NEIGHBORS));

  return src.unmask(scaled, true);
};

var source = ee.ImageCollection('LANDSAT/LE07/C01/T1_SR');
var fill = ee.ImageCollection('LANDSAT/LE07/C01/T1_SR');
```

I loaded a table of boundaries and filter.

```
var Jordan = ee.FeatureCollection('USDOS/LSIB_SIMPLE/2017')
    .filter(ee.Filter.or(
        ee.Filter.eq('country_co', 'JO')));
        var clippedJordan = composite.clipToCollection(Jordan);
```

I displayed the results for Jordan; however, the SLC gaps appear not to be filled. I proceed to calculate the MSAVI2 values using these images, so the remaining gaps influence the results.

```
var mc = Map.setCenter(36.274, 31.682, 6);
var visParams = {bands: ['B3', 'B2', 'B1']};
Map.addLayer(clippedJordan, visParams, 'clipped composite');
```

Any advice would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

I am not up on the latest Landsat 7 gap-filling technology for SLC-off imagery, but here is a greatly simplified version of what you were trying to do.  I removed a lot of (unnecessary?) stuff, increased the kernel size by a lot, and increased the timeframe over which the median replacement is generated.  It might get close to what you want:

```
var cloudMaskL7 = function(image) {
  var qa = image.select('pixel_qa');
  var cloud = qa.bitwiseAnd(1 << 5)
                    .and(qa.bitwiseAnd(1 << 7))
                    .or(qa.bitwiseAnd(1 << 3));
  var mask2 = image.mask().reduce(ee.Reducer.min());
  return image.updateMask(cloud.not()).updateMask(mask2);
};

var l7 = ee.ImageCollection('LANDSAT/LE07/C01/T1_SR')
    .map(cloudMaskL7);

var kernelSize = 10;
var kernel = ee.Kernel.square(kernelSize * 30, 'meters', false);

var GapFill = function(image) {
  var start = image.date().advance(-1, 'year');
  var end = image.date().advance(1, 'year');
  var fill = l7.filterDate(start, end).median();
  var regress = fill.addBands(image); 
  regress = regress.select(regress.bandNames().sort());
  var fit = regress.reduceNeighborhood(ee.Reducer.linearFit().forEach(image.bandNames()), kernel, null, false);
  var offset = fit.select('.*_offset');
  var scale = fit.select('.*_scale');
  var scaled = fill.multiply(scale).add(offset);
  return image.unmask(scaled, true);
};

// TESTING CODE
var point = ee.Geometry.Point(36.124, 31.663);
Map.centerObject(point, 11);

var check = ee.ImageCollection('LANDSAT/LE07/C01/T1_SR')
    .filterBounds(point)
    .filterDate('2004-09-15', '2004-12-31');
var checkImage = ee.Image(check.first());
var visParams = {bands: ['B4', 'B3', 'B2'], min: 200, max: 5500};
Map.addLayer(checkImage, visParams, 'source');

// Test composite.
var checkStart = checkImage.date().advance(-1, 'year');
var checkEnd = checkImage.date().advance(1, 'year');
var composite = l7.filterDate(checkStart, checkEnd).median();
Map.addLayer(composite, visParams, 'median');

// Rough implementation for comparison.
var replaced = checkImage.unmask(composite);
Map.addLayer(replaced, visParams, 'simple');

// Fancy implementation.
var filled = ee.Image(check.map(GapFill).first());
Map.addLayer(filled, visParams, 'filled');
```

EDIT: The answer now shows how to map this over a collection.  Watch out, because I don't know how well this will scale.  If you decide to map it over a big area or long time series, you've been warned.

Comment: Thank you @Nicholas Clinton! Just to make sure I understand, I have to generate a 15 year time series in three month increments, so I will be changing the var source filter date.  Should I change the var l7 dates to always be the year before and after the selected three months?

Comment: Another question - this code generates a single tile of the filled Landsat 7 SR.  I have tried modifying the filterBounds(point) code to make it a polygon, but that generates errors.  Is it possible to apply the GapFill code country-wide?

Comment: You may want to modify the code to be able to be mapped over the entire collection.  Here it's just set up for that single test image.  I'd make the fill composite from a median of one year on either side of each scene you process.

Comment: Thank you @NicholasClinton. When I try to change the code to map over the collection by modifying the **var source = ee.Image(ee.ImageCollection('LANDSAT/LE07/C01/T1_SR')** then the GapFill code returns errors such as _src.bandNames is not a function_. Why would previously functioning code stop working?

Comment: I have updated the answer.  Please upvote and mark as answered if this meets your needs.